# How to give select tag an attribute in cake php?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How to give select tag an attribute in cake php ?

```
$options = array('0' => 'News', '1' => 'Movies');
    echo $this->Form->select('selectValue', $options, 0, array('id' => 'select') )
```

So that I can give a attribute `data-url` to every options

```
<select id="select" name="data[Video][gender]" >
  <option value="0" data-url = "/news" >News</option>
  <option value="1" data-url = "/movies" >Movies</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't :P or at least there's no easy way to do it...

You'll need to extend the FormHelper and override the `select()` method.

Something like:

```
class MyFormHelper extends FormHelper{
    public function select($fieldName, $options = array(), $attributes = array()) {
        //something like the original method but this time the $options 
        //is more than a simple key=>value array, so you'll need
        //to change the code to include the data-url
    }
}
```

and then call your helper using MyFormHelper, something like

```
//In the view
$options = array(
                 array('data-url'=>'/news','text'=>'News'),
                 array('data-url'=>'/movies','text'=>'Movies'),
);

$this->MyForm->select('field',array('options'=>$options))
```

That's the main idea. Hope this helps