# CakePHP 1.3 - Add extra attributes to select menu options

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How can I add additional attributes to my select menu option tags?  Like this:

```
<select class="test" name="data[Test][test]">
    <option value="1" data-price="100">My Option</option>
</select>
```

How do I add the `data-price="100"` ?

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->select('test', $options, null, array(
        'class' => 'test',
        'options' => array(
            'data-price' => 100
        )
    ));
?>
```

Comment: will this help you??  http://phppoet.blogspot.in/2012/07/cakephp-date-field-with-default-values.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this out:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/03/01/some-new-crazy-cakephp-tricks/

"Setting additional attributes for some select options"

Answer (score 3):

```
you can try this
    echo $this->Form->input('test', array(
                        'options' => array(
                                            1=>array(
                                            'data-price' => 100, 
                                            'value' => '1', 
                                            'name' => 'My Option'
                                        )),'class' => 'test')
                                    );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
$options = array(
    ...
    array('name' => 'United states', 'value' => 'USA', 'title' => 'the title that you want', 'class' => 'something'),
    array('name' => 'USA', 'value' => 'USA', 'title' => 'the other title that you want', 'class' => 'otherthing'),
 );

 echo $this->Form->input('test', array('type'=>'select', 'options'=>$options));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually build the select HTML

also you can refer [How to give select tag an attribute in cake php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881586/how-to-give-select-tag-an-attribute-in-cake-php)

Answer (score 0):

In cakephp 4

[look for documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#using-collections-to-build-options)

Controller

```
$countries = $this->Countries->find('all')->where([
            'active' => 1
        ]);

$options = $examples->map(function ($value, $key) {
    return [
        'value' => $value->id,
        'text' => $value->name,
        'data-flag' => $value->iso_code
    ];
});
```

In view/template

```
<?= $this->Form->control('country_residence_id', [
                'label' => false,
                'options' => $countries,
                'class' => 'form-control select2-flag-search',
                'data-placeholde' => __('Select Country')
            ]) ?>
```